# gzip and config.php

Tags: ee2

In my control panel (EE 2.11.whatever) I have gzip turned on.  However in config.php, there's a part where

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

Do these conflict?  Turning it on and off in the control panel has an obvious effect according to NewRelic.

Comment: i never use the gzip features of EE, just roll my own in htaccess. prevents a lot of strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

You not need to give it from config file. You can direct put leverage browser caching to `.htaccess`
This method is easy to implement and direct htaccess triggered.

```
# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

# BEGIN ZIP
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
# END ZIP
```